# bbpress forum date Thu Jan 1970

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

I have a Code in my forum.php

```
<?php global $post;
$lalaposttime = date( 'D M Y', strtotime( $post->post_id ) );
echo $lalaposttime; ?>
```

But I get “THU JAN 1970” now. (I’d prefer the exact date)

Comment: `$lalaposttime = date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime( $post->post_id ) );` Read more about the options you have : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php

Comment: I don't found not one true answer in forums for this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never get a correct Date I guess, `strtotime` needs a valid date string, but you are providing an ID `$post->post_id` shouldn't be a `$post->post_date` or a valide string date !

**Edit**

After seeying your dump : Channge `$post->post_id` to `$post->post_date_gmt`

Comment: can you help me, how can I do it ?

Comment: just after the line `global $post;` add `var_dump($post); die;` and show me what you get.

Comment: object(WP_Post)#617 (29) { ["ID"]=> int(1769) ["post_author"]=> int(20) ["post_date"]=> int(0) ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2017-09-25 15:01:06" ["post_content"]=> string(8765) "